# i am not getting month/year slider using jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery

i want to get month/year picker slider on right side of my website.i got a code from one site.it is working,but after i download its not working.i added jquery.js folder.is it right.please help..my code is

```
<script src="jquery.js"></script>
    <script src="jquery.min.js."> 
    $(function() {
        $('.monthYearPicker').datepicker({
            changeMonth: true,
            changeYear: true,
            showButtonPanel: true,
            dateFormat: 'MM yy'
        }).focus(function() {
            var thisCalendar = $(this);
            $('.ui-datepicker-calendar').detach();
            $('.ui-datepicker-close').click(function() {
    var month = $("#ui-datepicker-div .ui-datepicker-month :selected").val();
    var year = $("#ui-datepicker-div .ui-datepicker-year :selected").val();
    thisCalendar.datepicker('setDate', new Date(year, month, 1));
            });
        });
    });
           </script>

    <style type="text/css">
    ui-datepicker-calendar {
        display: none;
     }
    </style>
    <label for="myDate">Date :</label>
    <input name="myDate" class="monthYearPicker" />
```

please help.whicj jquery i have to include?jquery.js or jquery.min.js?

Comment: Remove `src` from second `<script>`. `jquery.min.js` is basically minified version of `jquery.js`, there won't be any difference except size of the file. If you are developing use `jquery.js` and once moved to production use minified version.

Comment: Don't include compressed as uncompressed jquery. Include onlye one of them. Include jquery ui files also.

Comment: i  removed  src,but it s not working

Comment: press `F12` and check for console errors

Comment: Other then that its working fine!! check it **[here](https://jsfiddle.net/Guruprasad_Rao/Lyw2h0nz/)** and I hope `ui-datepicker-calendar` is a class so you need to refer with `.` preceeding while applying styles in CSS as I have in my demo.

Answer (score 0):

You have to include correct files:

**HTML:**

```
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.4/jquery.min.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.11.4/themes/smoothness/jquery-ui.css">
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.11.4/jquery-ui.min.js"></script>
<label for="myDate">Date :</label>
<input name="myDate" class="monthYearPicker" />
```

**JS:**

```
$(function () {
    $('.monthYearPicker').datepicker({
        changeMonth: true,
        changeYear: true,
        showButtonPanel: true,
        dateFormat: 'MM yy'
    }).focus(function () {
        var thisCalendar = $(this);
        $('.ui-datepicker-calendar').detach();
        $('.ui-datepicker-close').click(function () {
            var month = $("#ui-datepicker-div .ui-datepicker-month :selected").val();
            var year = $("#ui-datepicker-div .ui-datepicker-year :selected").val();
            thisCalendar.datepicker('setDate', new Date(year, month, 1));
        });
    });
});
```

Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/lotusgodkk/GCu2D/797/

Comment: if i want to display this month/year picker page on load what i have to do

Comment: Change the label to the div. The datepicker will show on load. OR just trigger focus on the input on load.

Comment: when on load displaying calendar also.i just want a month/year portion only,below calendar i dont want,please guide